# Is there a lower limit for how short a note can be, in a given time signature?

Tags: theory, time-signatures

A given time signature, say common time, establishes a limit for how long a note's value can be (nothing bigger than a whole note would fit in a 4/4 bar), but does this imply also a lower limit? For example, can a 4/4 accommodate figures smaller than a sixteenth note?

Comment: You can have a note as long as you want by use of ties, of course.

Comment: There is no upper limit and there is no lower limit. There are means to notate very long notes (much longer than one bar) and very short notes.

Comment: @WheatWilliams But a note longer than one bar can only be notated with ties, right? Double, long and large notes **cannot** appear in a 4/4 signature, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a 4/4 measure can accommodate figures smaller than 16th notes.

There are [32nds and 64ths and 128hs and 256ths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_value)! There are triples of 16th notes that are smaller than the normal 16th notes. There are irrational rhythm groupings, called [tuplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuplet); values like quintuplets (5 notes) and  sextuplets (6 notes) and  groups that have 7,8,9,10 notes in them,. Quite a few of the above are really rare, because they are really hard to play. Usually you will meet them at slow songs.

And to answer your question about the lower limit, I would say the 256ths might be. I've never seen anything below that, and if there was, it would be extremely hard to play.

Comment: In fact, already 64th notes are very seldom used, and even 32nd notes tend to belong to the virtuoso/flourish realm (except in very slow pieces).

Comment: I'd say the reason music rarely features 64th is that it's just too hard to count the flags/bars when they're that thick.

Comment: If one needs to go that small, it's far easier to halve/quarter  the tempo. Pretty pointless doing much else, really.

Comment: "extremely hard to play" depends on tempo ^.^  imagine if the tempo is one beat per month.  256ths are a breeze =)

Answer (score 2):

Music notation is designed to be flexible, and give as few hard limits as possible. There are practical limits on things on how finely you can divide a note: the average musician will have trouble counting much finer than a sixteenth or a thirty-second while sight-reading. And anything beyond a 128th or 256th would be very hard to read at all because with more than four or five lines, musicians would have to pause to count them and cheaply printed music can blur the lines.

But if you were writing a satirical piece and wanted to include a few measures with 2048th notes at a 10 bpm, it would be legal, just like writing fffffffff is legal to demonstrate very loud. But if you give musicians a marking of fffffffff, it will be no louder than an normal fff. And if you give musicians something as ludicrous as a 2048th note, they may reinterpret your music into something they can more easily handle, like rewriting your 6 second beats into several measures each.